# VBA Error: "The extract range has a missing or invalid field name"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Please see code below. The error in the title is occurring on each advanced filter line. I've made sure that the header row from the extract range matches exactly to the criteria range (no leading or trailing spaces), the destination is clear, the named range exists in Name Manager and includes the header row. I'm at a loss for what could be going wrong with this. I've also tried `Range.Select` to make sure that the range is selectable and that works as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("UG").Range("A3:Z1000").Clear
    Sheets("OH").Range("A3:Z1000").Clear
    Sheets("EC&M").Range("A3:Z1000").Clear
    Sheets("ETG").Range("A3:Z1000").Clear
    Sheets("Compare").Range("A1").Value = "Planner Updated: " & Date
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1").Value = "Updated: " & Date
    
    Sheets("All Tasks").Range("RefinedData").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("OH").Range("C1:C2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("OH").Range("A3"), Unique:=False
    Sheets("All Tasks").Range("RefinedData").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("UG").Range("C1:C2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("UG").Range("A3"), Unique:=False
    Sheets("All Tasks").Range("RefinedData").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("EC&M").Range("C1:C2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("EC&M").Range("A3"), Unique:=False
    Sheets("All Tasks").Range("RefinedData").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("ETG").Range("C1:C2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("ETG").Range("A3"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this event handler in a different sheet from the ones mentioned in the code?

Comment: Difficult to suggest much here without something to look at.  If you can share a version of your file which replicates the problem (but with dummy data) that would be useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, it is on a different sheet than the sheets in the code. Though it was like that before and it stopped working and I can't nail down what caused it to break